# Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json,laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5.3, eloquent, laravel-controller

I'm trying to retrive data from a database but I get the error “Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/"”.

Page loads with JSON array.

```
[{"id":1,"pic":"C:\\Users\\extra\\Downloads","type":"img","events_id":1,"created_at":"2017-04-18 19:16:02","updated_at":"2017-04-18 19:16:02","event":null},{"id":2,"pic":"background-pics-12.jpg","type":"img","events_id":2,"created_at":"2017-04-18 19:16:02","updated_at":"2017-04-18 19:16:02","event":null}]
```

I'm unable to use data to insert it in any tags. This is the code of the view.

```
 <section class="no-padding" id="media">
        <div class="container-fluid">

       <ul id="hexGrid">
<!--@foreach($items as $item)

 <li class="hex">
        <div class="hexIn">
          <a class="hexLink" href="#" id="{{$item->id}}"  role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal"  data-target="#myModal">

            <img src="{{$item->pic}}" alt="" />
            <h1>sdfghjk</h1>
            <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>

          </a>
        </div>
      </li>

@endforeach
-->
</ul>
</div>
</section>

  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
 <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>-->

  <!-- Modal -->
   <div class="modal fade" hidden="true" id="myModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="panel panel-filled">
                <div class="panel-body">
                       <div class="modal-header">Events</div>
                <div class="modal-body">

  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" >
         <!-- Indicators -->

    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
<script>
var xmlhttp;

    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

 // var xhttp1=new XMLHttpRequest();

     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
     {
        if(this.readyState==4 && this.status==200)
        {
                  var arr=JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                  console.log(arr.result.length);
                  console.log(arr);
                  var count=arr.result.length;
                  if(count!=0)
                  {
                    for(var i=0;i<count;i++)
                    {
                      if(arr.result[i].Type=='img')
                    {  var listelement=document.createElement("LI");
                      listelement.setAttribute('id', arr.result[i].ID);
                     listelement.className += "hex";
                      var div=document.createElement("div");
                      div.className += "hexIn";
                      var image=document.createElement("img");

                      var heading=document.createElement("h1");

                      var parag=document.createElement("p");

                      image.src=arr.result[i].image.replace("\\","");

                      heading.innerHTML=arr.result[i].Date; //content of  heading
                      parag.innerHTML=arr.result[i].Name;
                      var anchor=document.createElement("a");
                      anchor.className += "hexLink";
                      anchor.setAttribute('href',"#");
                      anchor.appendChild(image);

                      anchor.appendChild(heading);
                      anchor.appendChild(parag);
                      div.appendChild(anchor);
                      listelement.appendChild(div);
                      var ule=document.getElementById("hexGrid");
                      ule.appendChild(listelement);
                      anchor.onclick = function(){

  };
                    }
                    else {var listelement=document.createElement("LI");
                      listelement.setAttribute('id', arr.result[i].ID);
                     listelement.className += "hex";
                      var div=document.createElement("div");
                      div.className += "hexIn";
                      var image=document.createElement("iframe");

                      var heading=document.createElement("h1");

                      var parag=document.createElement("p");
                      var divv=document.createElement("div");
                      image.style["width"] = "auto";
                      image.style["height"] = "auto";
                      image.src=arr.result[i].image.replace("\\","");

                      heading.innerHTML=arr.result[i].Date; //content of  heading
                      parag.innerHTML=arr.result[i].Name;
                      var anchor=document.createElement("a");
                      anchor.className += "hexLink";
                      anchor.setAttribute('href',"#");
                       divv.appendChild(image);
                      anchor.appendChild(divv);

                      anchor.appendChild(heading);
                      anchor.appendChild(parag);
                      div.appendChild(anchor);
                      listelement.appendChild(div);
                      var ule=document.getElementById("hexGrid");
                      ule.appendChild(listelement);}
                    }
                  }
                  else { var parag=document.createElement("p");parag.innerHTML="nmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmo";
                var ule=document.getElementById("hexGrid");
                      ule.appendChild(parag);};

        }
   };

     xmlhttp.open("POST","/",true);
     xmlhttp.send();
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myModal").on("show.bs.modal", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      //var id1 = $(e.relatedTarget).data('target-id');
     // var id2 = $(e.relatedTarget).data('target');
      var id3 = e.relatedTarget.id;

    //  console.log('Val1=' + id1 + '; Val2=' + id2 + '; Val3=' + id3);

      $.get('/' + id3, function( data ) {
          alert(data);
          $(".modal-body").html(data);
      });

  });
});
</script>
```

And this is the controller's code.

```
 public function getmedia()
    {
            $event=Events::all();
             $items = Media::with('event')->get();
             $e=$items->unique('events_id');
             $e->values()->all();
             return response()->json($e);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure it's an error, and not a warning? Is the problem not perhaps with inserting and not the MIME type?

I'm also going to make a suggestion that when you post code, do not include code that is commented out. To focus on the problem we need to see the real working code. We can't guess if the commented code is relevant or not so it just takes longer and is more frustrating to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `Content-Type: application/json` header in your.

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","/",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xmlhttp.send();
```